# Changing the Foreground colour of a ContentPresenter containing a ContentTemplate and TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, contentpresenter

I have the following code, it is a button with a geometric icon

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Button}" IsEnabled="False">
    <DockPanel>
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource geometryMenuContentTemplate}"
                        DataContext="{StaticResource keyboardButtonGeometry}"
                        Style="{StaticResource TopBarIcon}" />
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TopBarHeaderText}" Text="KEYBOARD"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Button>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="geometryMenuContentTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Canvas>
        <Path Width="25" Height="25" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>

<StreamGeometry x:Key="keyboardButtonGeometry">
    F1 M 15.8333,2...
</StreamGeometry>
```

Styled with:

```
<Style x:Key="Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource StandardForegroundColor}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter Name="ButtonContentPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextBlock.Foreground="Red"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>


<Style x:Key="TopBarHeaderText" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource StatsHeaderText}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

The visual output of my code is the following:

[image: Button aspect]

I'd like to change (in `ButtonTemplate`) the foreground color of the `Textblock` inside the `ContentPresenter` called `ButtonContentPresenter` to red color.
My code changed the color only of the icon and not the `TextBlock`. Why?
How to change **only the `Textblock` color**?

I'd like to get something like this:

[image: Final image]

Comment: Your TextBlock is not inside the ContentControl and your Style is targeting button controls anyway and not TexBlock controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through your code, I noticed that your TextBlock has a style named TopBarHeaderText, But I don't see that style in your question. The reason the image is changing color is because you have it set as the Fill being {TemplateBinding Foreground} - maybe put that setting in the style for the TextBlock (the TopBarHeaderText style)?

It just looks like (from the code I am seeing) that you may have accidentally flipped the color definitions in the geometryMenuContentTemplate and TopBarHeaderText.